# Are these infinite sum identities on the real unit interval new?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a,b \in [0,1]$. Set $a_1 = a$, $b_1 = b$, and define inductively $a_{n+1} = a_n(1-b_n)$ and $b_{n+1} = b_n(1-a_n)$.
Then

$$\sum_n^\infty a_nb_n = \text{min}(a,b)$$

We have proven this result for $\omega$-complete effect monoids (of which $[0,1]$ is an example) in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1145/3373718.3394742), but I was wondering if it was already a known result for $a,b\in[0,1]$.

Note that the special case $a=b$ gives $a_n=b_n$ and hence $a_{n+1} = a_n(1-a_n)$ and $\sum_n^\infty a_n^2 = a$. In particular, for $a=\frac12$ the first few terms are $a_1=\frac12$, $a_2=\frac14$, $a_3 = \frac{3}{16}$, $a_4=\frac{39}{256}$. Does this ring a bell for anyone?

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A076628 for the case that $a=b=1/2$.